# Can I suggest the authors to hire professional writer for scientific paper as a reviewer during second review?

Tags: publications, research-process, peer-review, writing, literature-review

I have reviewed a scientific paper and suggested a major revision. They corrected it but still, I think the language quality is not standard. In this case, can I ask the authors to hire a professional writer? Is it ok if I ask them now because this is the 2nd review?
Or I just ask the editor if he can suggest the authors hire a professional writer?

Comment: I think you can, and in some cases should, make it a condition of acceptance that the language quality should be brought up to an acceptable level. But you shouldn’t specify the precise mechanism by which the authors achieve that, eg requiring that they hire a professional writer. (This was discussed on another question at some point, try the search feature.)

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Can I, as a reviewer, tell authors to get a native English speaker to proofread their paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/60576/7734)

Comment: Actually its slightly different. I asked if it's possible during the second review

Comment: @BlackSheep: Well, most answers to that question already advise against it for the first review.